# How to set selectedindex for UITabBarController's More view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

How to set **setSelectedIndex** to **UITabBarController** to display our view controller which exists inside **More View**.

I tried to set index using following code

```
    // To redirect user to home screen
    TBDDashboardTabBarController *tabBar = segue.destinationViewController;
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:5];
```

But since only max of 5 tabs will be displayed by iOS and index is beyond visible tabs given indexed view controller is not being displayed.

If I set the **setSelectedIndex** as **0 to 3** like `[tabBar setSelectedIndex:2];` it works great. Problem starts only if I try to set index greater than 3.

I tried in *Google, stackoverflow* and in other forums but no luck.
The closest hint is [How to get UIMoreListControllers child view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812108/how-to-obtain-child-view-controllers-of-uimorelistcontroller-a-private-framewor)

Please help me to solve this riddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the controller you need using `selectedViewController`. Swift code:

```
destination.selectedViewController = destination.viewControllers![4]
```